# shill script for C++ in linux

Tags: c++11

I have a C++ code and I need to run it 2000 times and print the results of all runs in a text file or data file. I can run it from the terminal by:

- g++ -o program_name  program_name.cpp
- ./program_name

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is, how I can do that?

Comment: You could use a shell script or a batch file depending on your platform. You could write another program to run that one in a loop. You could add a loop to your existing program to perform the logic multiple times. It isn't clear if your program already outputs the data you're interested in or if you're asking about that too. Try focusing on a more specific problem and show what you've done so far to try and get it to work.

Comment: my program already outputs data but it is a random simulation so, I need to run it many times i.e 1000, and collect all results in output file (file.data or file.txt).

Comment: You mean you use random numbers? And each run is an independent realization?

Comment: Yes, I use random numbers and each run gives a different result. so, I need to collect the results of 2000 runs.

Comment: What is a typical output of `./program_name`?

Comment: The output of this program is (ACTUAL TIME: 343.793  EXPECTED TIME: 343.406  DIFFERENCE: 0.38683 )